# How do I merge without losing commit history?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

So this is a big one. I created branch change-branch as mentioned below and I need to merge changes from 1.3.6 and 1.4.1 into this branch. Now the problem is that I want to selectively merge the changes. I don't want all the changes from 1.3.6 into change-branch. how do I go about this one?

This is the structure

```
master
|- track1
|- track2
|---|- msr-657
|---|---|--1.4.1
|---|---|--change-branch
|- track3
|---|-- 1.3.6
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four ways: using the `merge` command with the `--no-commit` flag, using `revert` after a `merge`, a selective `rebase`, or using `cherry-pick`.

Merging with `--no-commit` is probably the best for keeping the history around, but it will be more work since you will need to rollback changes manually before committing.

Another option is to `merge`, then selectively `revert` changes using `git revert`. This will only make the history messier, though.

If you don't care about the history being "pure", you can simply use `rebase`, but this only works safely if you haven't already pushed your changes to the common repo (if you are working with others) or you do the rebase from a throw away branch. You would do something like this:

```
git rebase --interactive master 1.3.6
```

This would `rebase` your changes onto master from `1.3.6`, but would first let you choose which commits to keep, edit, or ignore. I am pretty sure it will delete any branch you are doing a `rebase` from, so you should probably make another throw away branch in the same place as `1.3.6` before you `rebase`, then make `master` point to the same commit as the throw away branch, then finally delete the throw away branch.

Using `cherry-pick` allows you to selectively merge commits, but without explicitly remembering both parents. If the `1.3.6` branch is kept in the original repo, it isn't a super big deal to not have both merge parents since you still have the history somewhere, and `cherry-pick` can automatically reference the commit number in the description. This creates an impure history like a selective `rebase` does.

In the end, it depends on whether you are keeping around the `1.3.6` branch and how you want your history to eventually look.

Answer (score 2):

*git cherry-pick* is the simplest. you can *git cherry-pick* any commit you want into the current HEAD. you can also try *git cherry-pick A..B* to cherry pick all the commits from A's child to B.

*git rebase* is also powerful enough to do the job, but it's a bit tricky and confusing.